# How to avoid getting null on user location result in android?

Tags: android, location

In my app I am using `FusedLocationProviderClient` to get user location every time he enters the app by `mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener()`.But sometimes result is null,I am using  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` in manifest.How can I get user location even if it not so correct?Because the logic of app depends on that location,I don't need to show it on map or smth like that,just get the location.Thx in advance

Comment: google maps, waze, etc, doesnt work without location services on. its not uncommon for you to REQUIRE  a permission.

Comment: @DroiDev for example if I would take the user location every 30 minutes,getLastLocation() can still be incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use getLastLocation().  There is always a chance to have it return null if it doesn't have a location currently..  Use requestUpdates or requestSingleUpdates-  when the callback for those is called the location is guaranteed to be non-null.  getLastLocation() should only be used as an optimization to improve speed, it cannot be relied on.

Comment: Thank you very much,but is seems fusedlocation doesn't have requestSingleUpdates() method

Comment: THen do requestUpdates and unregister in the first update

Answer (score -1):

Follow the following example and your app is guaranteed to work as you wish. I have recently used this code and it is working like a charm.

Only thing you should know is that for the location updates to actually work ( to get real latitude and longitude values) you should enable "google play services". There may be several ways to do this but perhaps the simplest of all is to open "settings" on your device and probably somewhere under "security" or "permissions" (depending on your android distribution) find "google play services" and give it the permission it needs.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates